# How to bubble events from inner components to application controller in Emberjs?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am learning Ember and writing a simple login app with Emberjs. I have a login-box component - which handles the UI and backend communication. Upon successful login, I want to store current user somewhere so that all controllers can access current user object in the app. How can I do that? I am bubbling up events from LoginBoxComponent using this.sendAction('action'). The event is bubbling up to LoginController correctly(Login Controller's template invokes the component) - However since loginController is not in parent path of all controllers(I assumed applicationController is parent of all controllers - correct me if I am wrong), I am letting the event bubble up to application controller by not handling it in LoginController. However rails complains with

> Error: Nothing handled the action 'userLogin'. If you did handle the
>   action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action
>   handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

templates/login.hbs

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
  {{login-box store=store action="userLogin"}}
</div>
```

my success handler in components/login-box.js

```
  onSuccess: function(post) {
    console.log(post);
    this.sendAction('action');
  },
```

code in controllers/application.js

```
  actions: {
    userLogin: function() {
      this.set('currentUser', '123');
      this.transitionTo('index');
    }
```

However, If I handle this action in applicationRouter, it gets handled correctly - I dont understand why its skipping application controller. I dont want to handle it in application router because I can't set a global currentUser object from there.

Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions sent from components first go to the template's controller.

If the controller does not implement a handler for that action, it will bubble to the template's route, and then up the route hierarchy. For more information about this bubbling behavior, see [Action Bubbling](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling).

So your action is bubbling: Login Controller => Login Route => Application Route.

Comment: ah makes sense. Then how can I set a global currentUser to be used across all controllers in ApplicationRoute? do I have to use controllerFor and set it on ApplicationController? Does all controllers default to looking up in ApplicationController if they can't find a property set on them?

Comment: This answer is correct, but it is being [phased out](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_closure-actions)! I suggest the OP migrates to 1.13 and learn the new way.

Comment: @Anish when the action bubbles up to the ApplicationRoute,  you can use `this.controller.set()` to set a property on the ApplicationController.

Comment: @Anish: "Then how can I set a global currentUser to be used across all controllers in ApplicationRoute?" - It depends, difficult to answer in two words. You could find answer here http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/.   "Does all controllers default to looking up in ApplicationController if they can't find a property set on them?" - No.